# How to retrieve CRM dyamics account record from contactId

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, xrm

I am building a dynamic form where user can select any entity and its fields. and if field is lookup, user can select field from look so far it is working fine except for contact/account.

When I get contact entity metadata of contact it has account lookup but when i try to retrieve using all account column attribute does not returned.

Below is the code and attribute result i am getting.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusing thing here is that accountid and parentcontactid are not actually fields on the contact table. They are "virtual" fields provided by the CRM application for simplifying things like workflow operations where you need to target a specific type of parent customer record.

You need to instead use the parentcustomerid field which is the lookup to the parent account or parent contact. The parentcustomeridtype field tells you which type is referenced (account = 1, contact = 2). Fortunately this is generically handled by the EntityReference object and you can probably treat it about the same as any other lookup in your code.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the issue, but in this case by code is not generic, I have to made a check on contact entity if accountid is selected by user, i need to replace it with parentcustomerid. 
Are there any other case where this could happends ?

Comment: I think you should be fine aside from parentcustomerid.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has implemented functionality that Retrieve Multiple does not return attributes which has value null. That's why you are not getting all attributes.

References: 
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/289412

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/retrieve-detect-changes-metadata